# What's the meaning of this question?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have something to ask

I got a question from a reviewer who examined my paper as follows.

- In conclusion the authors have reported that slip flow was observed. How much times it was?

At that time, I understood that he was wondering how long it takes to observe slip flow. So, I explained about all the information related to our experiment. However, he questioned again by sentencing the below question.

- My question in previous comments was "what slip factor has been observed (e.g., 2 times, 10 times, etc.)?" Slip factor increases with decreasing pore sizes specially when size is in 1 order nanometer scale the slip factor can be even 100 times.

For the question, I didn't make sense what his question is about. I need some comparison between initial and final? Or I should point out how many times the slip flow was observed? Please let me know to understand his intend.

Thank you.

Comment: In the first question, _how much times_ is throwing you off because it isn't worded correctly. He's asking for the slip factor you observed.

Comment: The reviewer has used incorrect grammar. There's no way to know whether they meant to say "how many times" or "how much time." You should clarify this with them.

Comment: Ask *them*. Why are you asking a bunch of random strangers off the Internet instead? The reviewer knows exactly what he wants, and is being paid money to tell you. Neither is true of random strangers off the Internet. You have all the context, and you still don't understand. But then we are supposed to do better with little to no context. Not cool. Not cool at all. **Always ask the person you are talking to. Never wait for them to go away to ask random strangers off the Internet.**

Answer (score 1):

My sympathies.  You have to decipher a comment in English by someone who doesn't seem fluent in English.

> How much times was it?

is not idiomatic English.  Your first (reasonable) guess was that he meant **duration**:

> How much time did it take?

That apparently isn't what he's asking.  Another reasonable guess would be that he meant **number of occurrences**:

> How many times did you observe it?

But from his second comment, it seems that he's using "times" to mean **multiplication**.  I don't know what "slip factor" is, but it seems to be inversely related to pore size, i.e., the smaller the pore size, the greater the slip factor.  So another interpretation is

> You obtained a slip factor reading at an initial porosity.  By how many
>   **times** did the slip factor increase (i.e., by how many multiples of the
>   initial reading did the slip factor increase) as you decreased the pore
>   size?

Just a guess.  You'll have to say whether it makes sense.

(There's at least one other usage of times --not appliable here-- to mean an era, as in "my life and times."  Unfortunately for trying to understand the reviewer, it's a flexible word.)